# LibGDX JDK Version

Tags: java, gradle, libgdx, version, generator

I've wanted to create a game with libGDX recently. So I installed Oracle's JDK 12.0.1, downloaded libGDX's gradle-based project creation tool, and just tried to create a project at first. Hit generate button, it started to install gradle-4.6 version and failed to build cause gradle-4.6 does not support java 12.0.1. So my question is, how can I change the preferred gradle version and will the change solve my issue? Or do I have to work with JDK 8 for example because of Android.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refering to https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/documentation/gettingstarted/Setting%20Up.html, libGDX should support java 12 (if you don't want to export on Android, if so I would rather consider working with the JDK 8).

To remove the problem with gradle you just have to change inside the file located in project/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties, and change the distribution to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4-all.zip`

Comment: GradleScriptException could not ger unknown property “output” for SourceSet container of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSetContainer. I get this error, do you know how to resolve this?)

Comment: Gradle version change made gradle to recognize java version. But i think .gradle files generated by libGDX creation tool use deprecated api(

Comment: That's possible, but if that's really the case you will have to use an older version of gradle and java

Comment: I agree. But what do you think, is using old version of java that horrible, also how do you see the future of libGDX, if the dont even update their creation tool?)

Comment: No, I've been using java 7 and java 8 for a long time now, and I don't see that much things useful in the new versions of java (the console and all that stuff is very nice, but i've never really used it). So using java 8 or 9 should be very fine, and libGDX is still updated (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx, as you can see it has been updated 18 hours ago), so I think they didn't see the point of moving the project to the newest version of java, but the compatibility issue is strange, so maybe consider opening an issue over their github.

Comment: Agreed. Thx for spending your time helping me out. Good luck.

Comment: LibGDX stays at Java 7 because it's for Android, which uses somewhat upgraded Java 7. To use with Gradle 5+, search for `sourceSets.main.output.classesDir` and change that last part to `classesDirs`. Also, replace all the words `compile` with `implementation`